# supporting multiple screen in android

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-layout, user-interface

I am developing android application for tablet. 
My aim is to support for tablet from 7 inch to 10.1 inch.
i am unable to select proper layout according to my design.

1. if i am selecting linear layout then nested hierarchic increases.
   (according to UI design we should avoid nesting of layout).
2. if i am selecting relative layout then design is not match for all table.

please suggest which is best layout?

please help?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out would suit your best, I'd suggest you read the Android developer page on this topic: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For supporting multiple screen you have to create different  layout for different device .

you can more information from android developer site.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html